# Best linear unbiased estimator

Tags: bayesian, estimation, variance, unbiased-estimator, regularization

I have a sample of N stocks.

I have the following information:

- For each stock i, I have an estimate of variance (of returns) $\hat{\sigma}^2_{i}$.
- I also have a fitted variance, denoted by $\hat{b}_{i}$, estimated as follows:

$\sigma^2_{i} = \sum\limits_{k}  X_{i,k} * \beta_k + \epsilon$

where $X_i$ is NxK-matrix of known independent variables.

Then  $\hat{b}_{i} = \Sigma X_{i,k} * \hat{\beta}_k$ is the fitted variance, and where $\hat{\beta}_k$ is the OLS estimator of $\beta_k$.

I would like to combine each stock's variance estimate with the cross-sectional average, like

$\hat{\sigma}^2_{i, shrink} = w * \hat{\sigma}^2_{i} + (1-w) * \hat{b}_{i}$

The question is: what would a robust methodology to determine the appropriate weight $w$, that would minimize the standard error of this estimate $\hat{\sigma}^2_{i, shrink}$?

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly is a "cross-section average of variance"? Whatever it is, is it assumed to be known or is it estimated from the same data? What information do you have about correlations among the returns?

Comment: It is estimated at each time cross-sectionally by running a regression of sample variance of N stocks against some factors (factor model). I have updated my post to explain how it is estimated.

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like the answer must depend on how you estimate the $\hat\beta_k$, so you ought to explain that, too.  What you are doing remains a murky: although you state you are estimating a "fitted variance ... at each time $t$", your formula for it makes no reference to $t$ at all. Does time actually play any role here or are you just performing a sequence of independent estimates, one for each time? Regardless, how do you estimate $\hat\sigma^2_{i,t}$ for a *single* stock $i$ at a *single* time $t$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I am performing a sequence of estimates. That is why I dropped the $t$ subscript for simplification. As for $\hat{\sigma^2}$, it is estimated as the sample variance over the interval $[t-h,t]$.

Comment: It would be *much* simpler and less confusing, then, not to mention time at all.  But that leaves us puzzling over how you come up with $\hat\sigma^2_{i,t}$, since it seems you would have only one observation for each $i$.

Comment: You are right, I agree, let me adjust my post then. I have also added information about estimation of $\hat{\beta}_k$, which is simply the OLS estimator of $\beta_k$. With this new information, do you have an idea of how to solve the problem?

Comment: I too, am having trouble following the notation in this question (eg, what indices are being summed over, what is random and what is fixed, etc).  But you might do some reading on empirical bayes variance shrinkage in gene expression experiments.  Canonical reference is Smyth 2004 (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16646809)

Comment: You put a Bayesian tag. What is the Bayesian connection?

Comment: It refers to Bayesian Adjustment (Shrinkage).